# How to download songs in ionic App and only play within the App

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I build an app that downloads the songs from my server so that the user can listen to that songs offline. But I want user can only listen to that songs from my app, no other app can access that songs.

I have user CordovaFileTransfer plugin for downloading the songs. but it visible in file manager.Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks in advance